# HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException

Tags: error

New to Craft and following the tutorial to [Create the blog](https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/configure/section.html). When trying to browse the created blog page get 404 error below.

```
HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
Template not found: blog/_entry

1. in /data/www/example.org/sub/craftcms/main/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php at line 92
8384858687888990919293949596979899100101

    {
        // Does that template exist?
        if (
            (
                Craft::$app->getConfig()->getGeneral()->headlessMode &&
                $this->request->getIsSiteRequest()
            ) ||
            !$this->getView()->doesTemplateExist($template)
        ) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Template not found: ' . $template);
        }
 
        // Merge any additional route params
        $routeParams = Craft::$app->getUrlManager()->getRouteParams();
        unset($routeParams['template'], $routeParams['template']);
        $variables = array_merge($variables, $routeParams);
 
        return $this->renderTemplate($template, $variables);
    }

2. craft\controllers\TemplatesController::actionRender('blog/_entry', ['entry' => craft\elements\Entry])
3. in /data/www/example.org/sub/craftcms/main/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php at line 57 – call_user_func_array([craft\controllers\TemplatesController, 'actionRender'], ['blog/_entry', ['entry' => craft\elements\Entry]])
4. in /data/www/example.org/sub/craftcms/main/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php at line 181 – yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams(['template' => 'blog/_entry', 'variables' => ['entry' => craft\elements\Entry], 'p' => 'blog/headline-goes-here'])
5. in /data/www/example.org/sub/craftcms/main/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php at line 190 – yii\base\Controller::runAction('render', ['template' => 'blog/_entry', 'variables' => ['entry' => craft\elements\Entry], 'p' => 'blog/headline-goes-here'])
184185186187188189190191192193194195196

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function runAction($id, $params = [])
    {
        try {
            return parent::runAction($id, $params);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            if ($this->request->getAcceptsJson()) {
                Craft::$app->getErrorHandler()->logException($e);
                if (!YII_DEBUG && !$e instanceof UserException) {
                    $message = Craft::t('app', 'A server error occurred.');
                } else {

6. in /data/www/example.org/sub/craftcms/main/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php at line 534 – craft\web\Controller::runAction('render', ['template' => 'blog/_entry', 'variables' => ['entry' => craft\elements\Entry], 'p' => 'blog/headline-goes-here'])
7. in /data/www/example.org/sub/craftcms/main/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php at line 271 – yii\base\Module::runAction('templates/render', ['template' => 'blog/_entry', 'variables' => ['entry' => craft\elements\Entry], 'p' => 'blog/headline-goes-here'])
265266267268269270271272273274275276277

     * @param string $route
     * @param array $params
     * @return Response|null The result of the action, normalized into a Response object
     */
    public function runAction($route, $params = [])
    {
        $result = parent::runAction($route, $params);
 
        if ($result !== null) {
            if ($result instanceof Response) {
                return $result;
            }
 

8. in /data/www/example.org/sub/craftcms/main/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php at line 104 – craft\web\Application::runAction('templates/render', ['template' => 'blog/_entry', 'variables' => ['entry' => craft\elements\Entry], 'p' => 'blog/headline-goes-here'])
9. in /data/www/example.org/sub/craftcms/main/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php at line 256 – yii\web\Application::handleRequest(craft\web\Request)
250251252253254255256257258259260261262

        if (($response = $this->_processActionRequest($request)) !== null) {
            return $response;
        }
 
        // If we're still here, finally let Yii do it's thing.
        try {
            return parent::handleRequest($request);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $this->_unregisterDebugModule();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
 

10. in /data/www/example.org/sub/craftcms/main/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php at line 392 – craft\web\Application::handleRequest(craft\web\Request)
11. in /data/www/example.org/sub/craftcms/main/web/index.php at line 26 – yii\base\Application::run()
20212223242526

define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', getenv('ENVIRONMENT') ?: 'production');
// ...
 
// Load and run Craft
/** @var craft\web\Application $app */
$app = require CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH . '/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php';
$app->run();
```